# LINQ Count() with Case When

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have a SQL Server query and I rewrite this query in c# by using LINQ.

In the T-SQL query, there is a sum like that:

```sql
SELECT Date, 
   Name, 
   SUM(1)*(CASE WHEN Name='Sam' && Date=GETDATE() THEN 0.5 ELSE 1 END) AS 
   ItemCount, 
   SUM(ProductCount) AS ProductCount 
FROM ProductList
GROUP BY Date, Name
```

My Linq

```
var list = _context.ProductList
   .GroupBy(t => new {t.Date, t.Name})
   .Select(i => new ShipmentList()
   {
      Date = i.Key.Created,
      Name = i.Key.Name,
      ItemCount = i.Count(),
      ProductCount = i.Sum(x => x.ProductCount)
   }).ToList();
```

I can not complete the Case When after count `ItemCount= i.Count()`.
I tried like that:

`ItemCount= i.Count()*i.` this time I can not reach Name and Date
`ItemCount= i.Count()*y=>y.Name bla bla` again I can reach any column.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your anonymous type in the `GroupBy` has a `Date` and a `Name` property but not a `Created` property that you are trying to use. This should not compile

Comment: Don't get stuck there, it's just a typo, edited. My main question is about Count().

Comment: it's important anyway, since it shows us that this is just fake code that is not epxected to work. If possible provide compiling code so we know where to focus.

Comment: How should `SUM(1) * 0.5` ever return anything different than `0.5`? I don´t get your `ItemCount`, it will allways be either 0.5 or 1.

Comment: @HimBromBeere In SQL, the `SUM` is an aggregate operator, so it is essentially the same as the count of the members of the group.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x?

Comment: `CASE WHEN Name='Sam' && Date=GETDATE()` I am (cough) "surprised" that is valid SQL. I am also surprised that the date matches `GETDATE` exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You want a conditional `Count`? Since the [`Enumerable.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-5.0) overload with the predicate is not supported in Linq-To-Entities, you could try this approach:

```
var list=_context.ProductList
    .GroupBy(t=> new{ t.Date, t.Name})
    .Select(g => new ShipmentList
    { 
        Date = g.Key.Date, 
        Name = g.Key.Name, 
        ItemCount= g.Select(x => x.Name == "Sam" && x.Date == DateTime.Now ? 0.5 : 1.0)
                    .Sum() , 
        ProductCount = g.Sum(x => x.ProductCount)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Bye the way, that condition doesn't make much sense to me. But it's same as in your sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to translate directly by referencing `Key` for the groups:

```
var list = _context.ProductList
   .GroupBy(p => new { p.Date, p.Name })
   .Select(pg => new ShipmentList() {
      Date = pg.Key.Created,
      Name = pg.Key.Name,
      ItemCount = pg.Count()*(pg.Key.Name == "Sam" && pg.Key.Date == DateTime.Now ? 0.5 : 1),
      ProductCount = pg.Sum(p => p.ProductCount)
   }).ToList();
```

(Changed the range/lambda variables to make at least a little sense.)

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, thank you, did a copy paste :(